# Identifying Version of Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, version

Can someone with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1 installed on their server tell me what version is showing up on TFS Administration Console.

I'd like to find out if our server has been updated with SP1 or not?

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the console, if I go to Help....About Team Foundation Administration Console it shows:

> Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (30319.01)

You could also look in the View Installed Updates in the Programs and Features in Control Panel (depending on your OS).

Comment: Thanks Guthwulf. Could you confirm that you definiely have SP1 installed?

Comment: Yep. It is listed under Installed Updates as Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB218261).

Comment: - Slight adjustment to the KB number for anyone who finds this KB2182621

Answer (score 59):

Microsoft Team Foundation Server Support published the [complete list of all Team Foundation Server versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/) from 2005 onwards (till November 2013).

*The below chart lists the TFS Versions with Product Version number.
SP = Service Pack and CU = Cumulative Update*

- Team Foundation Server **2005**

  ```
  RTM             SP1
  8.0.50727.147   8.0.50727.762
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2008**

  ```
  RTM         SP1
  9.0.21022.8 9.0.30729.1
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2010**

  ```
  RTM             SP1             CU2
  10.0.30319.1    10.0.40219.1    10.0.40219.371
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2012**

  ```
  RTM             Update 1        Update 1 CU 1   Update 2        Update 3        Update 4
  11.0.50727.1    11.0.51106.1    11.0.60123.100  11.0.60315.1    11.0.60610.1    11.0.61030.0
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2013**

  ```
  RC              RTM             Update 2        Update 3 RC     Update 3        Update 4 RC     Update 4        Update 5    
  12.0.20827.3    12.0.21005.1    12.0.30324.0    12.0.30626.0    12.0.30723.0    12.0.31010.0    12.0.31101.0    12.0.40629.0
  ```

  There is no Update 1 for TFS 2013
- Team Foundation Server **2015**

  ```
  CTP             RC              RC2             RTM         Update 1 RC 1   Update 1 RC 2   Update 1        Update 2 RC 1       Update 2 RC 2       Update 2        Update 2.1      Update 3        Update 4 RC 1       Update 4
  14.0.22604.0    14.0.22824.0    14.0.23102.0    14.0.23128  14.0.24606.0    14.0.24626.0    14.0.24712.0    14.95.25005.0       14.95.25029.0       14.95.25122.0   14.95.25229.0   14.102.25423.0  14.113.26306.0  14.114.26403.0
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2017**

  ```
  RC1             RC2             RTM             Update 1 RC1    Update 1 RC2    Update 1 RTM (released on 7 March, 2017)    Update 1 RTM (released on 9 March, 2017)    Update 2 RC1    Update 2 RC2    Update 2 RTM    Update 3 RC1    Update 3 RTM
  15.103.25603.0  15.105.25716.0  15.105.25910.0  15.111.26117.0  15.112.26206.0  15.112.26301.0                              15.112.26307.0                              15.117.26526.0  15.117.26615.0  15.117.26714.0  15.117.26912.0  15.117.27024.0
  ```
- Team Foundation Server **2018**

  ```
  RC1             RC2             RTW
  16.121.26818.0  16.122.26918.3  16.122.27102.1
  ```

Comment: According to Mathieu Renda, in Team Foundation Server 2015 onward, the version number is displayed in the “About” page, reachable through the “Question mark” menu in the upper right corner of the web access. (This does not need administrative privileges).

Answer (score 6):

Open the folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools" and add the "File Version" column.  The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* DLLs with the highest version number indicate which updates have been applied:

> 10.0.30319.1 - TFS 2010 RTM
>   10.0.40219.1 - TFS 2010 with Service Pack 1
>   10.0.40219.371 - TFS 2010 with Service Pack 1 and Cumulative Update 2

Comment: Windows explorer -> View ->Choose Details.  In the popup check the box for "File version". (  I used Windows 7 enterprise , but should work on others)

Answer (score 1):

This helped:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have

But if for some reason you cannot get there because you don't have remote access to the server, you can check the  area of web.config (if you have access to that via ftp or something)

I found

```
<add key="applicationSettingsReader" value="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.WebApplicationSettings, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

in there.